# ERROR in disable hover effect in jquery after click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am using following code to disable hover effect of div after `click` function in `jQuery` but i get hover effect

### CODE

```
 $('.reveal').on('click', function(e) {
                var $that = $(this);

                e.preventDefault();
                ShowLoader();
                var link = $(this).attr('href');
                $('.page').load(link, function() {
                    HideLoader(); // this puts it in the load callback, so that this stuff
                    $that.show(); // happens when the load is complete
                });
                $('#leftmenu').css('width', '70px');
                $('#leftmenu').css('position', 'fixed');
                                    $("#leftmenu b,li ul").hide();
                $('li').unbind('click');
            });
```

to remove hover effect i add `$('#leftmenu').removeEffect(":hover");` but doest works

i need to disable hover effect of div after click function

**Need to disable this css function** `#leftmenuidfrmslt li:hover{color:red;background-color:#ffff66;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, `removeEffect` isn't a built in jQuery method. This is probably why you're getting an error.

Secondly, if you want to remove the CSS `:hover` effects, you'll have to define your styles in CSS, and then add/remove a class in your JS.

**CSS**

```
#leftmenu:hover {
  background: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* cancel out your :hover styles */
#leftmenu.no-hover {
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#leftmenu").addClass("no-hover");
```

Comment: only way is to add css can we do in scritp

Comment: Could do `$("#leftmenu").css({background:'transparent', 'font-weight':'normal'});` in JS, but it will be harder to reverse.

Comment: i need to disable hover effect

Comment: i need to disable th `<li>` item sorry

Comment: Then do `$("#leftmenu li").css(/*your styles*/);` instead.

Comment: i have added the css function which i want to disable after click

Comment: finally solved `$("#leftmenu li").css('background-color', 'white');` with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#leftmenu').off('hover');
```

or

```
$('#leftmenu').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: still i can see hover effect]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried .toggle()?

[Jquery docs](http://jqueryui.com/toggle/)

Comment: How would toggle help in this case? Toggle shows or hides an element, and the OP is asking about disabling a hover effect.